# SQL get data from different databases

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic, vbscript

I have 2 databases on the server names db_mdone and db_mdtwo. One of the columns in EACH database is the same named "Email" . That said, both databases have different columns. Can someone please help me in the SQL query to match the columns together and get the records? The records of db_mdone database is going to show at the top of the page and the records of the other is going to show at the bottom of the page. They dont need to be joined. thanks

Comment: What have you tried? what database are you running (MySQL, MSSQL, ORACLE?) please post the query you're working on.

Comment: SQL = " SELECT * FROM db_mdone, db_mdtwo WHERE Email = Email" I am a beginner

Comment: I am learning to do things and I managed to make this to work sSQL="SELECT * FROM tblmdfUK ORDER BY ID DESC". Now i have the problem I have explained above

Answer (score 4):

How about this ?

```
Select Email from db_mdone.dbo.firstTable 
union all
Select Email from db_mdtwo.dbo.secondTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax is fairly straightforward, you prefix the table name and schema with the server name e.g.

```
SELECT t1.Email 
FROM db_mdone.dbo.Table1 t1
INNER JOIN db_mdtwo.dbo.Table2 t2 ON t2.Email = t1.Email
```

(I'm not sure what you mean by 'matching up' so you'll need to work out your own actual query.

The best way to go about doing this I would say is to wrap it up in a stored procedure- you may need to use sp_addlinkeddserver to link the second server to the first assuming your connection string is to db_mdone

```
sp_addlinkedserver 'db_mdtwo'
```

Comment: I have a problem. what about the database connections? How I am going to connec tto two databases at the same time please?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your environment. You've stated 'sql' and asp-classic so I assumed SQL server - if using access or something else, add that to the question along with your current connection string (minus sensitive info)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient way of retreiving the data, but it is a start for you build upon.

```
<html>
<body>

<%
'=============================================================
' xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = IP Address for the SQL Server
' yyyyyyyy = User Id for the database
' zzzzzzzz = Password for the database
'=============================================================
strWebDSN = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;uid=yyyyyyyy;pwd=zzzzzzzz;database=db_mdone"
Set Conn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open strWebDSN 
set rs    = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from DATABASETABLENAME", conn

do until rs.EOF
        for each x in rs.Fields
             Response.Write(x.name)
             Response.Write(" = ")
             Response.Write(x.value & "<br />") 
        next
        Response.Write("<br />")
        rs.MoveNext
loop

rs.close
conn.close
%>

<hr>

<%
'=============================================================
' xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = IP Address for the SQL Server
' yyyyyyyy = User Id for the database
' zzzzzzzz = Password for the database
'=============================================================
strWebDSN = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;uid=yyyyyyyy;pwd=zzzzzzzz;database=db_mdtwo"
Set Conn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open strWebDSN 
set rs    = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from DATABASETABLENAME", conn

do until rs.EOF
        for each x in rs.Fields
             Response.Write(x.name)
             Response.Write(" = ")
             Response.Write(x.value & "<br />") 
        next
        Response.Write("<br />")
        rs.MoveNext
loop

rs.close
conn.close
%>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt mentioned table names.
You said that `one of the columns in each DATABASE` is called email. I imagine you have a table in the middle :)

Nevertheless, all the solutions provided so far don't deal with your last statement: `The records of db_mdone database is going to show at the top of the page and the records of the other is going to show at the bottom of the page`

Again, I imagine that by that you want all the record together, first the ones on db_mdone and then the ones on  db_mdtwo. If you actually want them in separate places of the page you will have to to two separate queries and deal with it on your application.

So, to achieve that I suggest you add a simple integer column on each select so you can use it to order the result:

```
select Email, 0 as order_column from db_mdone
UNION
select Email, 1 as order_column from db_mdtwo
ORDER BY order_column
```

this way, all records with 0 (db_mdone) are comming first and all the record with 1 (db_mdtwo) after